# How do I transfer csv to create a written prompt in a document using Python?

Tags: java

At my job we use Excel a lot and we are encouraged to automate with anys to point me in the right direction because I do not even know how to phrase this in google without getting topics or previous questions that do not help.

The code is what I have so far.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv (r'filepathway.csv')
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure thing.

Since Pandas series are mapping-like, you can use `str.format_map()` to easily interpolate your rows into a template string:

```
import pandas as pd

template = """
Store #: {store_no}
Currency Amount: {pennies} pennies - {nickels} nickels - {ones} ones - {fives} fives
Order Date: {order_date}
Expected delivery: {expected_delivery}
Confirmation Number: {confirmation_number}
""".lstrip()

# Example data to make this self-contained; could be `read_csv`'d.
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "store_no": [1, 2, 3],
        "pennies": [5, 10, 15],
        "nickels": [2, 4, 6],
        "ones": [7, 4, 11],
        "fives": [0, 0, 9],
        "order_date": ["2020-10-21", "2020-10-21", "2020-10-21"],
        "expected_delivery": ["2021-10-21", "2021-10-21", "2021-10-21"],
        "confirmation_number": ["12345", "54321", "98765"],
    }
)

for ix, row in df.iterrows():
    print(template.format_map(row))
```

This example df would look like

```
   store_no  pennies  nickels  ...  order_date  expected_delivery confirmation_number
0         1        5        2  ...  2020-10-21         2021-10-21               12345
1         2       10        4  ...  2020-10-21         2021-10-21               54321
2         3       15        6  ...  2020-10-21         2021-10-21               98765

[3 rows x 8 columns]
```

printed, and the loop starts printing out

```
Store #: 1
Currency Amount: 5 pennies - 2 nickels - 7 ones - 0 fives
Order Date: 2020-10-21
Expected delivery: 2021-10-21
Confirmation Number: 12345
```

etc.

If your CSV/Excel file's columns aren't named like this, you could use `df.rename()` to rename them.

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv()` as you have before. But as said in my post, you may need to rename some of your columns with `df.rename()`.

Comment: There will be an error message somewhere - and as I said, you will need to rename those columns so they match the template.